# Bitmap is seen as immutable when caling getPixels()

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I have the following code:

```
Bitmap mutableBitmap = result.bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(-result.rotationDegrees);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mutableBitmap, 0, 0, mutableBitmap.getWidth(), mutableBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
int[] intValues = new int[INPUT_SIZE*INPUT_SIZE];
rotatedBitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, rotatedBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, rotatedBitmap.getWidth(), rotatedBitmap.getHeight());
```

An `IllegalStateException` is thrown in the `eraseColor` method with the message **cannot erase immutable bitmaps** when `rotatedBitmap.getPixels` is called. Obviously, both `mutableBitmap` and `rotatedBitmap` are mutable bitmaps, that's why they exist, and the debugger confirms this as well. For completeness, `INPUT_SIZE` is the screen width and `result` is a `PhotoResult` object from `FotoApparat`.

So why is this exception thrown?

Answer (score 2):

I think your specific `createBitmap` method does not create a mutable bitmap:

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, int, int, int, int, android.graphics.Matrix, boolean)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20boolean))

"Returns an immutable bitmap from subset of the source bitmap, transformed by the optional matrix."

Comment: But if that's the case:
Why would the debugger tell me that `mIsMutable` is true for `rotatedBitmap`?

Why didn't it work either when I tried it the other way around, like:
`Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(result.bitmap, 0, 0, result.bitmap.getWidth(),result.bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);`
`Bitmap mutableBitmap = rotatedBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);`